# Missing Basic HTTP authentication entry in HTTP request header

Tags: c#, webclient

I have the following code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String un = "Username";
String pw = "Password";
client.Credentials =  new System.Net.NetworkCredential(un,pw);
client.DownloadFileCompleted +=
            new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(downloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), Config.LocalDir + @"\data\supportData.xml");
```

Using NetworkMonitor on the server I receive the following:

```
Http: Request, GET /audiClave/REST/en/actions 
Command: GET
URI: /audiClave/REST/en/actions
ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
Host:  210.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
Connection:  Keep-Alive
HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

No Authentication entry. What am I missing?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the old fashioned way:

```
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(un + ":" + pw));
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;
```

IIRC WebClient doesn't send the Authorization request header until it gets a challenge from the server with 401.