# Setting Authorization Headers and accessing data response in Sabre in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sabre

I am building a website to search for flights data using [Insta Flight Search API](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/air/search/instaflights_search) by Sabre. After thoroughly reading the docs provided by them and testing the API in the [API Explorer](https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs) where everything worked perfectly giving me the exact idea how the API will work.

To start with i just created a simple form with 2 select boxes which are providing the source and destination IATA codes, and 2 date input boxes giving the departure and return date. I have been searching for solutions for more than a week and tried various solutions i found, but every time i get either a **400 BAD REQUEST** or **401 UNAUTHORIZED** response.

I also checked the [Demo Gallery](https://github.com/SabreDevStudio) but at the time of writing there was no sample for C#, even on Stack-Overflow there are only 78 questions tagged sabre and just 1 tagged sabre and C#

I contacted the support but received a response.

> Please bear in mind that we do not provide code support. Could you please share the XML (Sabre) files?

I know i am missing something really silly, but after trying everything i can think of, i am resorting to the community for help. I am attaching both the code files.

Note: Commented code represents the various methods i have tried

**Controller Code :**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sabre_sample_1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
            {
            string Origin = Request.Form["Origin"];
            string Destination = Request.Form["Destination"];
            DateTime Departure = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["Departure"]);
            string departuredatestr = Departure.Year.ToString() + "-" + Departure.Month.ToString() + "-" + Departure.Day.ToString();
            DateTime Return = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["Return"]);
            string returndatestr = Return.Year.ToString() + "-" + Return.Month.ToString() + "-" + Return.Day.ToString();

            WebClient datawebclient = new WebClient();
            string url = "https://" + "api.test.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=" + Origin + "&destination=" + Destination
                + "&departuredate=" + departuredatestr + "&returndate=" + returndatestr + "&onlineitinerariesonly=N"
                + "&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=N&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc"
                + "&pointofsalecountry=US";
            string data = string.Empty;
            string AccessToken = "*Access Token*";
            //datawebclient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
            //datawebclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + AccessToken);
            //datawebclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, AccessToken);
            //data = datawebclient.DownloadString(url);

            //HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
            //data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //url = "https://www.theidentityhub.com/{tenant}/api/identity/v1";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
                data = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                // Parse JSON response.

            }

            ViewBag.url = url;
            ViewBag.data = data;
            //RedirectResult redirectresult = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

**Index.cshtml :**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Details</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Origin</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="Origin" required>
                <option></option>
                <option value="JFK">John F. Kennedy International Airport</option>
                <option value="EZE">Ministro Pistarini</option>
                <option value="MIA">Miami International Airport</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Destination</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="Destination" required>
                <option></option>
                <option value="JFK">John F. Kennedy International Airport</option>
                <option value="EZE">Ministro Pistarini</option>
                <option value="MIA">Miami International Airport</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Departure</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Departure"required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Return</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Return" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <input name="endpointName" type="hidden" value="Air Search" class="form-control">
            <input name="methodName" type="hidden" value="InstaFlights Search" class="form-control">
            <input name="httpMethod" type="hidden" value="GET" class="form-control">
            <input name="methodUri" type="hidden" value="/v1/shop/flights" class="form-control">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<h2>Url</h2>
@ViewBag.url
<hr />
<h2>Data</h2>
@ViewBag.data
```

Other Stack Overflow Questions which are closest to my problem, but didn't solved my problem.

- [c# - Webclient / HttpWebRequest with Basic Authentication returns 404 not found for valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044313/webclient-httpwebrequest-with-basic-authentication-returns-404-not-found-for-v)
- [c# - Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)
- [c# - How do I encode and decode a base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)
- [How to post data to specific URL using WebClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp)

**FINAL EDIT**

After weeks of struggling with the possible solution, i found the answer in the formatting of the response. A JSON object contains the objects as strings in " enclosing, but the whole response is also a string which makes the internal " enclosing to \"

But last month have made me realize the need for a proper tutorial for Sabre for developers in ASP.NET MVC C#, so i will publishing a blog post and a Nuget Package for other peers. I'll share the links once they are live.

Comment: Maybe its a kind of a stupid question, but have you tried to use BasicAuthentication and `NetworkCredential`?

Comment: @Andrew yes i have tried Basic Authentication and NetworkCredential also

Comment: @Downvoter Please leave a feedback describing the reason for your downvote of an year old question, instead of simply downvoting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of struggling with the possible solution, i found the answer in the formatting of the response. A JSON object contains the objects as strings in " enclosing, but the whole response is also a string which makes the internal " enclosing to \"

But last month have made me realize the need for a proper tutorial for Sabre for developers in ASP.NET MVC C#, so i will publishing a blog post and a Nuget Package for other peers. I'll share the links once they are live.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine for me.

```
FlightObject f = new FlightObject();
string URL = "https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/shop/flights?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2016-02-04&returndate=2016-02-20&pointofsalecountry=US&passengercount=2";
using (var w = new WebClient())
{
    w.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, token_type + " " + access_token);
    string str = w.DownloadString(URL);
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FlightObject));
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)))
    {
        f = (FlightObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: for test environment Sabre do not work for many sectors use these iatacodes, its working for me.. also use api explorer  https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs  for successful request response...

Comment: Which namespace contains the Type FlightObject

Comment: Just copy the response from InstaFlights Search   https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs and then generate Classes objects for serialization using http://json2csharp.com/ link..

Comment: the question is not about parsing the data, its about authenticating the request. I am not able to even reach the serialization steps

Comment: Though this answer didn't solved the original question, i learned a new thing i.e. json2csharp so a +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're getting the Access Token first, using the `/v2/auth/token REST service`, right?

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_basics/authentication

Also, can you try this approach?

```
// Add this on top
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
// then......
//....... 

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
        data = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

    }
```

Comment: ooops. Sorry I just noted you tried that in your commented code.
Assuming you have obtained a correct access token using the /v2/auth/token service, then I can't see what's wrong with your code.

Have you tried with another REST client tool (e.g.: soapUI, Postman), to make sure you're setting all params correctly?

Comment: yes i am able to authenticate and receive an access token from the server perfectly fine without any issues.

Comment: In that case I'd try with a tool monitoring the traffic (http request uri and headers) generated from your app, and compare with the correct format (vs. Sabre API Explorer or another tool - e.g.: soapUI - that you know it's working)

Comment: thanks, monitoring of traffic led me in the right direction, i have posted the answer. +1 for the help.