# Is there any way I can get the results from php and use it on c#? Like for Login?

Tags: c#, php

This is my PHP file.

```
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from companies where company_username like '$user_name' and company_password like '$user_pass'";


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
echo "Company Login Successful";
}
else{
echo "Login Error! Please try again";
}
```

Should I use WebClient?
Sorry I'm just a newbie,thanks :)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use **[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24859910/1849024

Comment: It's not clear how you want to use c#?

Comment: Okay sir, thank you for telling me the flaws. I'll take note of that @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @JeremyThompson I got 2 text boxes where I can input username and password and check whether it exist on my database using the php file

Comment: Yeah webclient or HttpWebRequest would be the two classes I'd use, at your level what ever is easiest

Comment: @imsome1 thank you. I will check that out

Comment: @JeremyThompson I salute you sir. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite some possibilities. I will present one, but this is far from the single one.

First of all I would not use the standard content type (most likely `text/html`, but I have not checked it). You could use JSON or XML as a content type, I will use JSON here

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

This is not necessary, we could parse a JSON disregarded of the `Content-Type` header, but it's cleaner that way.

Next we will have to generate the output

```
$arr = array('Status' => 1, 'Message' => 'Company Login Successful'); //or otherwise, depending on if the login *was* successful
echo json_encode($arr);
```

On the C# side you can use `HttpClient` class to fetch the result.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync($"http://www.yourserver.net/login.php", loginHttpContent);
var stream = await httpResponseMessage.ReadAsStreamAsync();
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LoginResult));
var loginResult = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as LoginResult;
```

`LoginResult` class:

```
[DataContract]
class LoginResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**Please note:** The code provided is *just a sketch* and not at all production-ready. For example you should not create the HttpClient or the `DataContractJsonSerializer` at this point, dispose resources correctly, handle exceptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for solutions and I saw a simple way to get the results from PHP...

```
private void SubmitData()
{
try
{
     string user = tbUsername.Text;
     string pass = tbPassword.Text;
     string url = "--my_php_url--";

     WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
     NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
     formData["user_name"] = user;
     formData["password"] = pass;

     byte[] responseBytes = webclient.UploadValues(url, "POST", formData);
     string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
     MessageBox.Show(responsefromserver);
     webclient.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception e )
{
MessageBox.Show("Error :" + e.Message);
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)