# Java Web service - c# soap client array serialization

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, web-services, wsdl

I need to write a c# client to consume a PHP WebService.
In the WSDL there is an object whit the following xsd:

```
<s:complexType name="affiliazione">
<s:annotation>
</s:annotation>
<s:sequence>
<s:element name="disciplina" type="s:string" nillable="false" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<s:annotation>
</s:annotation>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

The way Visual Studio creates the corresponding xml is the following:

```
<q2:affiliazione id="id1" xsi:type="q2:affiliazione">
<disciplina href="#id2"/>
</q2:affiliazione><q3:Array id="id2" q3:arrayType="xsd:string[1]"       xmlns:q3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <Item>AG010</Item></q3:Array    >
    </affiliazione>
```

But the server accepts only the following format:

```
    <affiliazione xsi:type="rss:affiliazione">
      <disciplina>AG010</disciplina>
      <disciplina>CJ014</disciplina>                        
     </affiliazione>
```

where the array "disciplina" is written in a flat way.
I tried to decorate the object "disciplina" in the proxy with the XmlElement and DataMember but with no success.

Could you please help me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: did they give you a url for the particular wsdl also checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821637/calling-a-php-webservice-from-c-sharp