# WebRequest will not pass headers

Tags: c#, webrequest

i have trolled and tried everything, i have done this 100's of times before without issues but now im stumped.

I simply want to pass header info from a webrequest.

The client runs separately and connects to a wcf rest service.  The service has this code which gets hit:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
```

The client has this:

```
    var client = WebRequest.Create(url);
    client.Method = type.ToString().ToUpper();
    client.ContentType = "application/json";
    client.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    client.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: {0}", "test12345"));
```

I have also tried for example:

```
    client.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "test1234";
    client.Headers["Authorization"] = "test1234";
```

No matter how i try and set the headers they are never passed.  When I look at the request in fiddler, Authorization is NEVER there.  I have also tried to send X-Requested-With, etc... but no matter what the header will not pass.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I found the issue, but not the solutions:
[WebRequest will not pass headers when used from within ASP.NET MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022647/webrequest-will-not-pass-headers-from-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: That Authorization header does not look valid according to the standard and is probably being stripped. If you want to use a custom Authorization header perhaps use a different Header name? As a test what happens if you change your header name to something different?

Comment: I have used this format before and it worked fine, but for funzies i have tried other ways, i have updated my post to reflect.  Thanks for the reply :-)

Comment: also what happens when you set it the more tradtional way, eg `client .Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");` (nb this will produce a different output to what you have above)

Comment: nothing gets added to the headers when doing .Credentials.  Sad thing is I have done this MANY times before.  I just dont understand why i cannot pass header info regardless ;-(

Comment: I gotta admit, there is something strange going on. When I first copied your code and tried it on google.com the Authorization header was NOT sent. Then I tried it on a server that required Auth and it was sent. Then I went back to google.com again and now it is sent! Very strange

Comment: @wal - thats odd.  Yea i have never had any issue sending headers before... although I cannot say i have done it since updating to .net 4.5 - maybe that has something to do with it... hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Does the server require authentication? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440255/missing-basic-http-authentication-entry-in-http-request-header?lq=1) answer the WebRequest will not send credentials until challenged. If you want to send it regardless you may need to use a different class than `WebRequest` to send the request, eg RestSharp

Comment: Yes auth is required, but I have tried sending other headers, not just 'Authorization'.  I control the service too so i even tried something crazy like allowing 'Test12' .. adding that on the client still doesnt send it.

Comment: @schmoopy can you do a `Console.WriteLine("foo1")` in your client side code to ensure its compiling and sending your changes?

Comment: Yes, i did a Debug.WriteLine...   hello from the console!!!
Good suggestion tho.  I just cleaned out all 'Temp. asp.net files' too just in case but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WebRequest you can use RestSharp. It has a simple abstraction and API.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is maybe a little too late (found this when looking for some answers to my question).

Don't know if it will help you, but mine is like this and I have the Authorization header in the server side and I'm using 4.5.1.

Client Side

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "basic " +
            Convert.ToBase64String(
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}|{1}", "login", "password")));

string result = string.Empty;
using (WebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Server side

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DefaultRequestHeaders

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("test12345")