# WebRequest will not pass headers when used from within ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webrequest

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that when I make an http call using a webrequest, the headers will not pass.

The same code in Linqpad I can set info in the headers such as AUTHORIZATION and it works fine (I can see the header values in Fiddler)

However, when I do the same code from within my MCV controller then the headers do not pass.  Its as if ASP.NET MVC is overriding my headers.

Any suggestions?

```
        var client = WebRequest.Create(url);
        client.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization:{0}", "Fun-Kitty"));
        client.Headers.Add(String.Format("X-Requested-With:{0}", "PowerFlower"));
        client.Method = "GET";
        client.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse resp;
        using (resp = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse())
        {
            if (resp.GetResponseStream() != null)
            {
                var status = resp.StatusDescription; // TODO
                var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                var obj = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:
Please note that the headers are setting correctly (except when called from with MVC Controller) - setting the header various ways has no impact (ie: works in Linqpad, not in MVC Controller)

```
    client.Headers.Set("Authorization", "PwrUp");
    client.Headers["Authorization"] = "ababab11ab";
    client.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization:{0}", "Fun-Kitty"));
```

This code passes the headers just fine from LinqPad or a Winforms/WPF App BUT NOT from ASP.NET MVC Controller.

I also notice when inspecting the header that when the call is made from the MVC controller, the following value is set (not sure if it has anything to do with it though):

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove the white space on the right side of the `:` on your header adds:

```
client.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization:{0}", "Fun-Kitty"));
client.Headers.Add(String.Format("X-Requested-With:{0}", "PowerFlower"));
```

Alternatively, use the overload that takes 2 string parameters:

```
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Fun-Kitty");
client.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "PowerFlower");
```

Per the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/965xw3x5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The header parameter must be specified in the format "name:value".

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The way I set the headers are fine, i removed the whitespace just for test but same results.  These settings (with or without whitespace) work fine from Linqpad or a Winform app, just not within ASP.NET MVC Controller.

Comment: I have a theory @schmoopy. Try casting the create to `HttpWebRequest`: `var client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this but the results are the same.

Comment: @schmoopy alright now I'm curious. Disassembling the `WebRequest` code, stand by...

Comment: @schmoopy try using `Set(string, string)` instead of `Add(string, string)` on the headers. I feel that this will work. I'm not totally sure why yet.

Comment: No luck, i have tried all of the different ways of setting the header(updating post to reflect) - they all work except when called from within  the MVC Controller.

Comment: @schmoopy that doesn't make sense to me, as MVC doesn't intercept. I'm gonna have to chalk it up to environment somehow. Sorry I'm not more help.

Comment: Thats ok, thanks so much for all of your investigation - agreed it makes no sense whatsover.  I have rebooted, cleard asp.net cache - nothing makes sense.  Thanks again :-)